# How many degrees can you flex an arm of a lego minifig?

Tags: minifigures

How flexible are the arms of Lego minifigs?

Comment: Do you mean bending the actual arm, or rotating them within the shoulder socket?

Answer (score 13):

Within the shoulder socket, a minifigure's arm has full 360° rotation, however the hand needs to positioned correctly to allow it pass the head, and it puts some strain on the joint:

[image: Arm next to head]

Note that most accessories will block this rotation.

As the arms are made of the same ABS as standard LEGO bricks they aren't flexible, and so without heating (and permanently changing them) they don't bend or flex.

Comment: I tried this on a minifigure with the hands cupped like in [this](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/185/132) example. It's actually possible to swing the arm 360° without the arm bending too noticeably out of it's socket.